# Express checkout email receipt items not shown

Tags: node.js, paypal

My customers are receiving the email receipt from **PayPal** with no items shown. Only the total is shown (Email screenshot below).

[image: Email receipt screenshot]

But on cart before the payment, the items appear

[image: Cart Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

The `npm` module:
`paypal-express-checkout`

Here's the `params` that I'm using to create the payment request.

```js
params['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'+i]  = cart.items[key].preco.toFixed(2);
params['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'+i]  = cart.items[key].qtty;
params['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'+i] = cart.items[key].nome;
```